# React: nested object with useRef doesn't update correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am using react, and I got a nested object like this:

```
const obj = useRef({
    category1: [
      { title: { name1: 'value1' } },
      { title: { name2: 'value2' } }
    ],
    category2: [
      { title: { name3: 'value3' } },
      { title: { name4: 'value4' } }
    ]
  });
```

When I trying to update the category1 by adding a newTitle object in category1[index], the title object got replaced.

what I want:

```
const obj = useRef({
   category1: [
     { title: { name1: 'value1' } },
     { title: { name2: 'value2' }, newTitle: { name5: 'value5' } }
   ],
   category2: [
     { title: { name3: 'value3' } },
     { title: { name4: 'value4' } }
   ]
 });
```

what I got:

```
const obj = useRef({
    category1: [
      { title: { name1: 'value1' } },
      { newTitle: { name5: 'value5' } }
    ],
    category2: [
      { title: { name3: 'value3' } },
      { title: { name4: 'value4' } }
    ]
  });
```

I tried few different ways and none of it works.

```
const titleVar = 'newTitle';

const nameVar = 'name5';

const valueVar = 'value5';

obj.current[ctg][index][titleVar] = { [nameVar]: valueVar };


obj.current = {
                    ...obj.current,
                    [ctg]: [
                        ...obj.current[ctg].slice(0, index),
                        {
                            ...obj.current[ctg][index],
                            [titleVar]: { [nameVar]: valueVar }
                        },
                        ...obj.current[ctg].slice(index + 1)
                    ]
                };

const temp = {...obj.current[ctg][index],
               [titleVar]: { [nameVar]: valueVar } };
 obj.current = temp;
```

Comment: attempts1 and 2 should work (assuming `ctg` is `"category1"`, `index` is `1` and that `titleVar` is in fact `"newTitle"` and not an existing key in your object that you're updating). There is most likely something else wrong in your code. How are you determining that `title` is getting replaced? Also

Comment: @NickParsons I console logged obj.curret before and after updating the code, unfortunately it didn't work as expected.

Comment: You might have to create a reproducible example: [mre] so that we can see the full picture. Just to be clear, `titleVar = 'newTitle'` The value of `"newTitle"` is what you're actually using in your real code? You'd get this sort of behavior that you're describing if `titleVar = 'title'`.

Answer (score 0):

When updating the nested object, you need to make sure to preserve the existing properties of the object while adding new properties. you aren't using spread operator properly. here is the snippet which will get you the result you desire. click on update Object button to update the obj.

```js
// Get a hook function
const {useState} = React;
const {useRef} = React;
const MyComponent = () => {
  const [obj, setObj] = useState({
    category1: [
      { title: { name1: 'value1' } },
      { title: { name2: 'value2' } }
    ],
    category2: [
      { title: { name3: 'value3' } },
      { title: { name4: 'value4' } }
    ]
  });

  const ctg = 'category1';
  const index = 1;
  const titleVar = 'newTitle';
  const nameVar = 'name5';
  const valueVar = 'value5';

  const updateObject = useRef(() => {
    const updatedObj = {
      ...obj,
      [ctg]: obj[ctg].map((item, i) => {
        if (i === index) {
          return {
            ...item,
            [titleVar]: { ...item[titleVar], [nameVar]: valueVar }
          };
        }
        return item;
      })
    };

    setObj(updatedObj);
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Object State:</h2>
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2)}</pre>
      <button onClick={updateObject.current}>Update Object</button>
      <h2>Updated Object State:</h2>
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2)}</pre>
    </div>
  );
};



// Render it
ReactDOM.createRoot(
    document.getElementById("root")
).render(
    <MyComponent />
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know anything about React, but I got the results you expected with this Vanilla Javascript code, which looks a lot like one of the things you tried:

```js
const obj = ({
    category1: [
        { title: { name1: 'value1' } },
        { title: { name2: 'value2' } }
    ],
    category2: [
        { title: { name3: 'value3' } },
        { title: { name4: 'value4' } }
    ]
});
const ctg = 'category1'
const idx = 1
const titleVar = 'newTitle'
const nameVar = 'name5'
const varVal = 'value5'
obj[ctg][idx][titleVar] = { [nameVar]: varVal }
console.dir(JSON.stringify(obj))
console.dir(obj)
```

Which is to say:

```json
{
    "category1": [
        {"title": {"name1": "value1"}}, 
        {"title": {"name2": "value2"}, "newTitle": {"name5": "value5"}}
    ], "category2": [
        {"title": {"name3": "value3"}}, 
        {"title": {"name4": "value4"}}
    ]
}
```